# Organizar o select do mysql por grupos do mês

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Estou tentando organizar um retorno do meu banco mysql em meses , ou seja , de forma que eu tenha grupos do meses das doações que o site que trabalho recebe , tentei assim:

```
SELECT * , MONTH(  `DataConfirmacao` ) FROM  `doacoes` WHERE Pendente =  '1'
```

Eu tentei usar o Group By , mas ele retornava somente o primeiro valor não todos.
Estrutura da tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` serve para agrupar por algum valor, o que você quer é o `ORDER BY`, que serve para ordenar:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    MONTH(`DataConfirmacao`) 
FROM 
    `doacoes` 
WHERE 
    Pendente =  '1' 
ORDER BY 
    `DataConfirmacao`;
```